# How to force android to install app on internal memory

Tags: android

I've an app that i download from private server, it installs ok on most phones but i'm having problems installing it on a HTC Desire C. The phone has no sdcard present. I've searched around and found a manifest setting that should hint at internal storage or say that there is at least no preference to where the app is installed.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.carefreegroup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:installLocation="auto" >
```

This does not work however.

How can i tell android that the app **MUST** be installed on the internal memory

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set in Manifest

```
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
```

this will install app in internal storage and will not install it at all if there is no space in internal memory

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: See you cannot totally control where the app will be installed, as per the docs you can simply specify the preference of it. Can you describe the exact scenario why you need this?

Comment: Hi yes of course. I've written an app that is on our private server. It's an app that is used by care workers. The app is rolled out to hundreds of companies. Each company can have up to 500 carers. My boss is at a company now demoing the app. The test phone is a desire C which i have downloaded the app on to. However my test phone i had to buy an sdcard to install app. The carer company has ordered a load of these phones that do NOT come with an sdcard on purchase. So i need a way of getting the app on to the phone without an sdcard.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can download the .apk via HTTP and install it on the phone, if you allow the "unknown sources" thingy.

Comment: yes i've checked that box allows unknown sources, that's not the problem, the phone will allow the download just not the install due to lack of sdcard present. The phone is saying there must be an sdcard present to install the app

Comment: what is the size of the app? how much free space is there in internal memory? what is going to be there n the app, i mean what will be content of app? and what message you get when you try the option internalonly in manifest? sorry for this questionnaire :)

Comment: @turtleboy I see what you're saying... Out of the blue, you could try to write an app to download the apk, store it in the internal storage and  then try to use the package manager to install it (http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98). I don't know if this is possible, however.

Comment: @droider lol questionaire, it's ok. Erm internal memory is ok 1GB avaliable. The app has a few backround images, services, asyncTasks, webservice calls, listviews, mapview etc. The error goes as follows. An sdcard is required to download myapk.apk thanks

Comment: @turtleboy: well, it has nothing to do with app settings. you are trying to download the app from somewhere and it is not able to download the apk in absence of sdcard. so need to find a way to get the apk on the internal memory

Comment: @droider exactly. or they will have to just buy an sdcard and then all is well in the world;)

Comment: @Droider i've just found this link as well regarding sdcard issue with the desire C. If you look at the paragraph headed 'lack of memory'. Apparently this phone doesn't come with sdcard but you need it to even store a camera shot!! Thanks and accepted your answer as that is what you would normally have to do with a decent phone;)http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/mobile_phones/htc/desire_c/434485

Answer (score 2):

The attribute **android:installLocation** can have following possible values.

**internalOnly:** The application must be installed on the internal device storage only. If this is set, the application will never be installed on the external storage. If the internal storage is full, then the system will not install the application. This is also the default behavior if you do not define android:installLocation.

**auto**: The application may be installed on the external storage, but the system will install the application on the internal storage by default. If the internal storage is full, then the system will install it on the external storage. Once installed, the user can move the application to either internal or external storage through the system settings.

**preferExternal:** The application prefers to be installed on the external storage (SD card). There is no guarantee that the system will honor this request. The application might be installed on internal storage if the external media is unavailable or full, or if the application uses the forward-locking mechanism (not supported on external storage). Once installed, the user can move the application to either internal or external storage through the system settings.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html) if you do not set that preference, the app will be installed on internal storage and it won't be movable.